# set plotly title in the bottom

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I try to put the title in the bottom. I saw the `yanchor = "bottom"` attribute but cant manage to use it.

Any idea ?

```
iris %>% 
  count(Species) %>% 
  plot_ly(labels = ~ `Species`,
                    values = ~n,
                    type = 'pie',
                    textposition = 'inside',
                    textinfo = 'label+percent',
                    insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
                    hoverinfo = 'label+percent',
                    showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  layout(title = "I need to be in the bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Just use `y = 0.1` or some other low number to adjust the position. [Change title position in plotly R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508442/change-title-position-in-plotly-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
iris %>% 
    count(Species) %>% 
    plot_ly(labels = ~ `Species`,
            values = ~n,
            type = 'pie',
            textposition = 'inside',
            textinfo = 'label+percent',
            insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
            hoverinfo = 'label+percent',
            showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
    layout(title = list(text = "I need to be in the bottom", y = 0.05))
```

Output:

[image]